# How to getElementsByTagName where elements are child of body tag

Tags: php

I have the following:

```
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
if ($node->item(0) == null || $node->item(0) == '') {
    // do stuff
} elseif ($node->item(0)->hasAttribute('src')) {
    // do other stuff
} else {
    // do more other stuff
}
```

What I want is to only return images from the body tag.

I have tried:

```
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
foreach ($body as $body_node) {
    $node = $body_node->getElementsByTagName('img');
}
```

however if there is an image in header it still seems to get returned by

`$node->item(0)->hasAttribute('src')`

Personally there should never be an img in the header but I find some url's add them in a noscript tag in the the header.

So how do I return only images from he body tag excluding any found in the head tag?

Comment: `$body->getElementsByTagName('img');` and iterate.

Comment: Isn't tha exacly what I am doing in the foreach loop with `$node = $body_node->getElementsByTagName('img');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it using [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//body//img');
```

`$nodes` is now a [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) that you can iterate over.

If you only want `img` nodes that have a `src` attribute:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//body//img[@src]');
```

**Edit:** Here is a fully working example:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($contents);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//body//img');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is still giving me he same issue. 

`$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc); 
 $node = $xpath->query('//body//img');
 if(isset($node) && $node->item(0)->hasAttribute('src')) {
 $firstimage = $node->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
}
`

using example below $firstimage is returning blah.jpg instead of the first image from the body

<head><noscrip><img src="blah.jpg"></noscript></head>